# Why am I getting odd results when ModalPopupExtender is opened from javascript in a User Control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using this script in a User Control (ascx) file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function ShowPopUp() {
        var id1 = window.$find('<%=ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID %>'); 
        id1.show(); } 
    </script>
```

The popup is coded here:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCosCodeExpCode" runat="server" CssClass="SVSTableCellTextBox1" ></asp:TextBox>

    <cc1:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" targetcontrolid="txtCosCodeExpCode" popupcontrolid="Panel1" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG"></cc1:modalpopupextender>
```

When the OK button is clicked, it should do this:

```
    ModalPopupExtender1.Hide();
    txtCosCodeExpCode.Text = ReturnCostCentreExpCode();
```

The User Control containing all this is repeated 10 times on the same page:

```
     <uc1:OrderLineControl ID="OrderLineControl1" runat="server" />
     <uc1:OrderLineControl ID="OrderLineControl2" runat="server" />
     <uc1:OrderLineControl ID="OrderLineControl3" runat="server" />
     <uc1:OrderLineControl ID="OrderLineControl4" runat="server" />
     <uc1:OrderLineControl ID="OrderLineControl5" runat="server" />
     <uc1:OrderLineControl ID="OrderLineControl6" runat="server" />
     <uc1:OrderLineControl ID="OrderLineControl7" runat="server" />
     <uc1:OrderLineControl ID="OrderLineControl8" runat="server" />
     <uc1:OrderLineControl ID="OrderLineControl9" runat="server" />
     <uc1:OrderLineControl ID="OrderLineControl10" runat="server" />
```

So when I use the tab key to move my cursor into the field txtCosCodeExpCode, it opens the Popup fine. I can make my selections and click OK. However, when the OK button is clicked, it is updating the WRONG txtCosCodeExpCode, i.e. if I am editing Line 2 or 3, it sticks the new value on line 10.

Comment: So is the `ShowPopUp()`, `txtCosCodeExpCode` and `ModalPopupExtender1` in each `OrderLineControlxx` or are they outside?

Comment: ShowPopUp(), txtCosCodeExpCode and ModalPopupExtender1 are in each OrderLineControl

Comment: Have you debugged yet, putting a breakpoint in the click event to verify they are each going into the correct handler?

Comment: Of course I have debugged. My click event looks like this: protected void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ModalPopupExtender1.Hide();
            txtCosCodeExpCode.Text = ReturnCostCentreExpCode();
            txtQty1.Focus();
        }

Comment: For a test, I would change `ShowPopup()` to `ShowPopup1()`, `ShowPopup2()`, `ShowPopup3()`, etc. inside of the controls.  See if it that pops up the right one.

Comment: I tried adding client id to my javascript and the onfocus call, like this: function ShowPopUp<%=ClientID %>() {
        var whatIsThis = '<%=ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID %>';
        console.log(whatIsThis);
       // alert(whatIsThis);
        var id1 = window.$find(whatIsThis);
        console.log(id1);
        id1.show();
    } and <asp:TextBox ID="txtCosCodeExpCode" runat="server" CssClass="SVSTableCellTextBox1" onfocus="ShowPopUp<%=ClientID %>()" ></asp:TextBox>
This last line does not make it past the compiler - error message: This is not scriptlet. Will be output as plain text.

Comment: Code Maverick - are you suggesting I make 10 different versions of my UserControl?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if your `ShowPopup()` is inside your UserControl, as you said it was, then it would stand that you have 10 functions named `ShowPopup()` and obviously the last one on the page is the one that will be called, which is why your editing line 2 or 3 ends up modifying line 10.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I could assign the different names to the script from code behind. I'll give it a go.

Comment: OK. I tried that. I created 10 versions of ShowPopup() - ShowPopup1(), ShowPopup2()... etc. It made no difference. I put this in the control and called it from the main page: public void AddOnFocusScript(int cI)
        {
            string scriptName = "ShowPopUp" + cI.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "()";         txtCosCodeExpCode.Attributes.Add("onfocus", scriptName);            txtCosCodeExpCode.DataBind();lblRow.Text = cI.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);}BUT there is still only one ModalPopupExtender,one panel being popped up,with one OK Button. Could this be the problem?